# Generate a variadic list at runtime

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

Let's say I want to handle square mesh grids of `N_DIMS` dimensions, each of `N_RES` elements length, which turns out in `N_ELEMS = std::pow(N_RES, N_DIMS)` elements.

The implementation I had to follow is a generalization for non-squared grids

```
template<typename T, size_t... DIMS>
class MeshGrid
{
   // ... etc etc
}
```

Such as a possible instance with 3 dimensions of respectively 4, 5, 6 elements could be

```
 MeshGrid<float, 4, 5, 6> mg; // call A
```

Now I like to adapt it to something like

```
template<typename T, size_t RES, size_t... DIMS>
class MeshSquare
{
   // ... etc etc
}
```

Preserving the `MeshGrid` inner `DIMS` logic, in order to do run-time calls such as **B**

```
int res = 4, dims = 2
MeshSquare<float, res, ??dims??> // call B
```

For an example square mesh of 2 dimensions, 4 elements each = 16 total elements.

I'm honestly suspicious about what I'd like to do; I have the feeling that variadic lists must be handled at compilation time; the **B** call above is a nonsense.

If it could ever be possible, my question is how to expand `dims` to fit **B** call.

Comment: Your feeling is on point: you can't generate template instanciations at runtime.

Comment: Yep. All templates are resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `MeshSquare` to be templatized on `dims`, then the only thing you can do here is to generate all the instantiations in advance and then `switch` at run-time. E.g.

```
switch(dims)
{
    case 0: foo<MeshSquare<float, res, 0>>(); break;
    case 1: foo<MeshSquare<float, res, 0, 1>>(); break;
    case 2: foo<MeshSquare<float, res, 0, 1, 2>>(); break;
    case 3: foo<MeshSquare<float, res, 0, 1, 2, 3>>(); break;
    case 4: foo<MeshSquare<float, res, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4>>(); break;
    // ...
}
```

You can easily generate these kind of switches with C++17 fold expressions, with compile-time recursion and `index_sequence`, and many other techniques. Alternatively, consider using a library that acts as a bridge between the run-time and compile-time world such as [`petra`](https://github.com/jacquelinekay/petra) (C++17).

---

A more appropriate solution might be simply not storing the dimensions as a template parameter, but use a more dynamic (run-time) data structure instead.